# Comparing 2 node sets based on attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is related to my previous question but i can't able to get solution for this. Here also i need to compare two node based on the attribute values but it's difficult to me. Pls provide the xsl to do this. thanks in advance.

input.xml:

```
<comp>
 <alink>
    <link id="#c1-0003"/>
    <link id="#c1-0001"/>
    <link id="#c1-0002"/>
 </alink>
 <bibsection>
    <bib id="c1-0001">
     <citation>
      <Name>Boud</Name> (<year>2007</year>)
      <vol>32</vol> (<issue>3</issue>
     </citation>
    </bib>
    <bib id="c1-0002">
     <citation>
      <Name>john</Name>(<year>2008</year>)
      <vol>32</vol> (<issue>3</issue>)
     </citation>
    </bib>
    <bib id="c1-0003">
     <citation>
      <name>nnc</name>(<year>2009</year>)
      <vol>32</vol> (<issue>3</issue>)
     </citation>
    </bib>
</bibsection>
 </comp>
```

output.xml:

```
<comp>
<alink>
  <link id="#c1-0003"/>
  <year>2009</year>
  <link id="#c1-0001"/>
  <year>2007</year>
  <link id="#c1-0002"/>
  <year>2008</year>
</alink>
<bibsection>
    <bib id="c1-0001">
     <citation>
      <Name>Boud</Name> (<year>2007</year>)
      <vol>32</vol> (<issue>3</issue>
     </citation>
    </bib>
    <bib id="c1-0002">
     <citation>
      <Name>john</Name>(<year>2008</year>)
      <vol>32</vol> (<issue>3</issue>)
     </citation>
    </bib>
    <bib id="c1-0003">
     <citation>
      <name>nnc</name>(<year>2009</year>)
      <vol>32</vol> (<issue>3</issue>)
     </citation>
    </bib>
</bibsection>
```

Comment: How would one *guess* the wanted year? In the provided XML document all years are 2007.

Comment: sorry i wrongly entered the year. this is the correct input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kBibById" match="bib" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kBibById', substring(@id, 2))/*/year"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to contain different years):

```
<comp>
    <alink>
        <link id="#c1-0003"/>
        <link id="#c1-0001"/>
        <link id="#c1-0002"/>
    </alink>
    <bibsection>
        <bib id="c1-0001">
            <citation>
                <Name>Boud</Name> (
                <year>2007</year>)       
                <vol>32</vol> (
                <issue>3</issue>
            </citation>
        </bib>
        <bib id="c1-0002">
            <citation>
                <Name>john</Name>(
                <year>2008</year>)
                <vol>32</vol> (
                <issue>3</issue>)      
            </citation>
        </bib>
        <bib id="c1-0003">
            <citation>
                <name>nnc</name>(
                <year>2009</year>)
                <vol>32</vol> (
                <issue>3</issue>)      
            </citation>
        </bib>
    </bibsection>
</comp>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<comp>
   <alink>
      <link id="#c1-0003"/>
      <year>2009</year>
      <link id="#c1-0001"/>
      <year>2007</year>
      <link id="#c1-0002"/>
      <year>2008</year>
   </alink>
   <bibsection>
      <bib id="c1-0001">
         <citation>
            <Name>Boud</Name> (
                <year>2007</year>)       
                <vol>32</vol> (
                <issue>3</issue>
         </citation>
      </bib>
      <bib id="c1-0002">
         <citation>
            <Name>john</Name>(
                <year>2008</year>)
                <vol>32</vol> (
                <issue>3</issue>)      
            </citation>
      </bib>
      <bib id="c1-0003">
         <citation>
            <name>nnc</name>(
                <year>2009</year>)
                <vol>32</vol> (
                <issue>3</issue>)      
            </citation>
      </bib>
   </bibsection>
</comp>
```

**Explanation**:

This is one of the shortest, simplest, most readable and most efficient solution to the problem.

The only difference from the solution of the previous problem is that now the values of the `id` attributes of `link` elements aren't exactly the same as the value of the `id` attributes of `bib` elements.

We need to extract the substring of any value of the former type, starting from the 2nd character (that is, to skip the 1st character). This is natural to do using the standard XPath **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)** function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XSLT transformation, but I guess the years in your example were wrong (in the input they're all 2007)

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!-- Generally copy all elements and attributes -->
<xsl:template match="*">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- For a link element, add the year -->
<xsl:template match="link">  
    <!-- Store the link id without the # -->
    <xsl:variable name='i'><xsl:value-of select='substring(@id,2)' /></xsl:variable>
    <!-- Copy the link element -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
    <!-- Add the year as a lookup in the input XML -->
    <year><xsl:value-of select='/comp/bibsection/bib[@id=$i]/citation/year/text()' /></year>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can set the variable directly: `<xsl:variable name='i' select='substring(@id,2)' />`. You can also omit `/text()` in the XPath getting the year.